# Why is Landing Altitude displayed in amber on B777?

Tags: flight-instruments, boeing-777, altimeter

When I set the landing altitude manually, an amber LDG ALT and Landing Altitude EICAS message is displayed. There are no failures nor has the landing altitude been set incorrectly.

Why do I still get the EICAS message ALT LDG in amber?

Answer (score 16):

The Boeing 777 is a very automated aircraft.  The takeoff altitude, landing altitude, and cabin pressurization altitude are all automatically set when you enter the departure airport and destination airport in the Flight Management Computer.

The EICAS message ALT LDG appears when the FMC is not controlling the landing altitude. This can be caused by one of three different conditions:

1) There is no destination airport entered in the FMC

2) The FMC landing altitude function has failed

3) The LDG ALT knob has been used to set the landing altitude manually

It is also normal to see ALT LDG after landing when the route has been dumped.

[image]

Comment: I used the knob to set it manually, but I thought if only the landing field value is incorrect, I will get amber light. --> so does this mean, I will always get amber light, doesn't matter if landing field is correct or incorrect ?

Comment: Yes, if you manually set the landing altitude, the amber EICAS message is telling you the FMC is not setting the landing altitude. You can clear the EICAS message but the underlying condition is still there and the message can be re-called to check the status.

Comment: thanks Mike for the answer, but what would be for example cause that FMC is not setting the landing altitude?

Comment: Not entering a destination airport is the most common reason, but malfunctioning software or hardware can also cause the FMC to not set the landing altitude.